# How to select class or id of textarea in jquery?

Tags: jquery, textarea

Hi all i am working on jquery i have a text area i need to select class for hide  functions in jquery once it load it will be displayed when i eneter and when i leave it should hide

here my code follows:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.select').mouseleave(function () {
        $('.select').hide();
      });
    });
   </script>
```

here my html:

```
     <textarea  rows="10"  class="select"  id="editor1"> </textarea>
```

here i have my textarea right i need when entered no function will be fired when i leave the textarea it shouls hide for that i need to call text area with class so i need to how to fine a textarea class any help wil be appreaiated thanks

Comment: You can add this textarea inside Div tag, and perform this Hide/Show operation on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $('.select').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).hide();
 });
```

Altho you might wanna try:

```
 $('.select').blur(function () {
    $(this).hide();
 });
```

And as per your question in title

```
$('.select') /* This will select every single element
    that has the class "select" */
```

Whereas

```
$('#editor1') /* This will select ONLY the first
    element that has the id "editor1" */
```

And inside any event or func call on an element, $(this) represents the element called:

```
$(".select").blur(function(e) {
    $(this) // represents the current element losing focus
});
```

Comment: yes i am sure i am keeping some alerts alerts are firing but function not firing

Comment: thanks i had tried its working right thank you verymuch thanks alot for my reply

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it right; although mouseleave is when the mouse hovers over it then leaves (hence the event name).

For text input you're better of using focusout; example below.

```
   <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.select').on("focusout",function () {
        $(this).hide();
      });
    });    
   </script>
```

Comment: try add console.log("message") to ensure that the event is firing; also might be a stupid question but have you double checked the element has the class ".select" try the ID instead as if this does fire it would hide all of the elements with the same class; I've edited my answer to include this